# Solspace SuperSearch and URL Rewrites

Tags: search, url, solspace, supersearch, rewrite

Can anyone help me with URL rewriting using Solspace SuperSearch as our SEO guys have suggested that these could be improved:

We have 5 dropdowns for make, model, fuel type, min price and max price. The form uses POST. Examples of the search results generated pages are:

**Blank Form**
`http://www.motors.coop/search/results/search&cf_make=&cf_fuel=&cf_price-from=0&cf_price-to=50001/`

**Make Only**
`http://www.motors.coop/search/results/search&cf_make=Audi&cf_model=&cf_fuel=&cf_price-from=0&cf_price-to=50001/`

**Diesel Only**
`http://www.motors.coop/search/results/search&cf_make=&cf_fuel=Diesel&cf_price-from=0&cf_price-to=50001/`

Standard stuff, you'll agree. What our SEO company has suggested that these be re-written to something like this:

`http://www.motors.coop/search/bmw/diesel/5001/18000`

I agree that these are cleaner - is there a regex someone can suggest that can achieve this? The big issue is a user may not necessarily choose ***anything*** from ***any*** of the dropdowns. In this case, can the URL be something like:

`http://www.motors.coop/search/all/all/all/1/100000`

Hope someone can help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Template Routes](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/template-routes) by Rob Sanchez. You should be able to setup a route with wildcards in a set order, then match those to each part of the segment that Super Search needs. Something like:

```
$config['template_routes'] = array(
    'search/:any/:any/:any/:num/:num' => 
    'search/results/search&cf_make=$1&cf_model=$2&cf_fuel=$3&cf_price-from=$4&cf_price-to=$5'
);
```

The other thing you'd have to do is make your search form redirect to the clean URL, but that should be fairly easy.